# How to Left Join two MySQL tables on two columns?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two tables that I'm trying to join.

Table1: T1

```
|id|date|hits|
--- ----- ------
A1   01   2
A1   02   2
A2   02   3
```

Table2: T2

```
|id|date|runs|
--- ----- ------
A1   01   1
A2   02   0
A3   02   2
```

The output:

```
|id|date|hits|runs|
--- ----- --- ---
A1   01   2    1
A1   02   2    0
A2   02   3    0
```

Each id has multiple dates and there are different hits/runs per date.

I have tried:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id) AND (t1.date=t2.date);
```

This gives me a HUGE table. With way more rows than T1.

There are more rows in T2 than T1, but I only care about dates in T1 hence the LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do without seeing a sample of data and what you expect to be output, but I'm going to guess that you don't have a correct understanding of what `LEFT JOIN` does.

`T1 LEFT JOIN T2` **does not** limit the number of rows to one per row of T1.

If there are multiple rows in T2 that match a given row in T1, the result of the join will include all the matching rows of T2.

What `T1 LEFT JOIN T2` does is output a given row from T1 even if there are *no* rows in T2 that match.

I'm guessing you probably want something like: output each row from T1, joined to the *latest* matching row from T2. If so, there are many solutions already posted on Stack Overflow. Look for questions tagged [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

---

Re your comment:

Thanks, I tested your query with the test data you supplied. It does not give the result you show. The result is:

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON (t1.id=t2.id) AND (t1.date=t2.date)
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.date;
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | date | hits | id   | date | runs |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| A1   | 01   |    2 | A1   | 01   |    1 |
| A1   | 02   |    2 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| A2   | 02   |    3 | A2   | 02   |    0 |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cece2/2

I think you are running a query different from what you have posted above. Maybe you mixed up `AND` versus `OR` in your join condition?

Comment: Hi, there are multiple values rows that meet t1.id=t2.id but there is only one match for t1.id=t2.id **AND** t1.date=t2.date. I added values to the comment for illustration

Comment: Thank you.  The problem I was having was I thought there was only one row meeting the `(t1.id=t2.id) AND (t1.date=t2.date)` restriction but upon reviewing the data I realized that was not the case.  I appreciate it